# python subprocess call bash script OpenFOAM

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, call, openfoam

I am on ubuntu 20.04 Linux with Python 3.8.10 and OpenFOAM is v2112.

I believed a simple **subprocess.call** should allow to run a bash script from a python one. The python script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess
subprocess.call("./BashTest")
```

The BashTest script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "${0%/*}" || exit    # Run from this directory
. ${WM_PROJECT_DIR:?}/bin/tools/CleanFunctions  # Tutorial clean functions
#---------------------------
cd case
cleanCase0
echo "BashTest " $(date +%s) > timeLog.txt
```

The bash script works from the terminal: the txt file is produced and the cleanfunction cleans what it has to.

The python script does not: the txt file is not produced. The cleaning is not done.

However, if I remove line 3 of the bash script,

> . ${WM_PROJECT_DIR:?}/bin/tools/CleanFunctions

, which refers to where the openfoam cleanfunctions are located, then the python script produces the txt file.

Therefore what could be wrong here ?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: "Nothing happens" -- if nothing includes no exception being thrown, the script most certainly did run.

Comment: BTW, `$SHELL` doesn't matter at all; `#!/bin/sh` forces `sh` to be used to interpret the script, ignoring the use of bash for your interactive interpreter.

Comment: Anyhow -- where I'd suggest you start here is to add `set -x` to your script to enable trace logging to stderr during its execution, and _read the logs on stderr_. If that doesn't do anything, it implies your real Python code is doing something like silently catching exceptions (which your sample code in the question _doesn't_ do), and you should stop that.

Comment: If those hints don't get you somewhere useful, we'll need a [mre] -- the shortest possible script we can run without any changes to see the same problem ourselves. "Minimal" means trying to remove as many moving parts as possible -- if you can demonstrate the problem by having the script `echo` something instead of sourcing openfoam code and executing something from it, f/e, you should do that as part of preparing the question.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. (On Ubuntu 20.04/Python3.8.10/OpenFOAMv2112)

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy for your comment. I have revised my post. Also, what do you mean about 'set -x' ? Where should I put it ?

Comment: Just below the shebang of your script, typically. If you want to see what it does, you can run it in an interactive shell -- `set +x` will turn that tracing back off.

Comment: That said, the edits have been helpful: `${var:?}` tells the shell interpreter to exit with an error if `$var` isn't set. In this case, then, we know that `WM_PROJECT_DIR` isn't set in your Python program's environment (you can check the environment as a whole by inspecting `os.environ`).

Comment: (BTW, `/bin/sh` is not bash -- even if it's actually a symlink to `/bin/bash`, which isn't always true, it runs in compatibility mode with some features turned off when started under the `sh` name; if you wanted your code to run with bash, you'd want `#!/usr/bin/env bash` instead).

Comment: ...another note: You can specify an error message to use by putting it after the `?`, as in, `. ${WM_PROJECT_DIR:?WM_PROJECT_DIR is not in the environment}/bin/tools/CleanFunctions`

Comment: ...of course, another possible problem is that `CleanFunctions` is built to be sourced only by bash and doesn't run with `sh`; but you wouldn't typically have that problem only when starting your script from Python.

Comment: thanks. but then how to set `WM_PROJECT_DIR` in the Python program's environment ?